AgGrid applyTransaction add produces duplicate rows with getRowId set to return primary key
Why is AgGrid transaction api allow adding duplicate rows with the same primary key from getRowId()
Is this by design or a bug?
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update-transactions/
Here is a code example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/8G36oeIsMRNzwPQu
Try click "Add Items" button multiple times, you will see duplicate rows with the same id is getting added.
data.js
export function getData() {
    return [
        {
            id: 1,
            make: 'Toyota',
            model: 'Celica',
            price: 35000,
            zombies: 'Elly',
            style: 'Smooth',
            clothes: 'Jeans',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            make: 'Ford',
            model: 'Mondeo',
            price: 32000,
            zombies: 'Shane',
            style: 'Filthy',
            clothes: 'Shorts',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            make: 'Porsche',
            model: 'Boxster',
            price: 72000,
            zombies: 'Jack',
            style: 'Dirty',
            clothes: 'Padded',
        },
    ];
}


main.js
import { createApp, onBeforeMount, ref, shallowRef } from "vue";
import { AgGridVue } from "@ag-grid-community/vue3";
import "@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css";
import { getData } from "./data.js";
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model";
import { ModuleRegistry } from "@ag-grid-community/core";
ModuleRegistry.registerModules([ClientSideRowModelModule]);

const VueExample = {
  template: `
        <div style="height: 100%">
                <div style="height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 4px">
        <button v-on:click="addItems(undefined)">Add Items</button>
        <button v-on:click="addItems(2)">Add Items addIndex=2</button>
        <button v-on:click="updateItems()">Update Top 2</button>
        <button v-on:click="onRemoveSelected()">Remove Selected</button>
        <button v-on:click="getRowData()">Get Row Data</button>
        <button v-on:click="clearData()">Clear Data</button>
      </div>
      <div style="flex-grow: 1">
        <ag-grid-vue
          style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
          :class="themeClass"
          :columnDefs="columnDefs"
          @grid-ready="onGridReady"
          :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
          :rowData="rowData"
          :getRowId="getRowId"
          :rowSelection="rowSelection"></ag-grid-vue>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    `,
  components: {
    "ag-grid-vue": AgGridVue,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const columnDefs = ref([
      { field: "make" },
      { field: "model" },
      { field: "price" },
      { field: "zombies" },
      { field: "style" },
      { field: "clothes" },
    ]);
    const gridApi = shallowRef();
    const defaultColDef = ref({
      flex: 1,
    });
    const rowData = ref(null);
    const rowSelection = ref(null);

    onBeforeMount(() => {
      rowData.value = getData();
      rowSelection.value = "multiple";
    });

    const getRowId = (params) => params.data.make;

    const getRowData = () => {
      const rowData = [];
      gridApi.value.forEachNode(function (node) {
        rowData.push(node.data);
      });
      console.log("Row Data:");
      console.table(rowData);
    };
    const clearData = () => {
      const rowData = [];
      gridApi.value.forEachNode(function (node) {
        rowData.push(node.data);
      });
      const res = gridApi.value.applyTransaction({
        remove: rowData,
      });
      printResult(res);
    };
    const addItems = (addIndex) => {
      const newItems = [
        createNewRowData()
      ];
      const res = gridApi.value.applyTransaction({
        add: newItems,
        addIndex: addIndex,
      });
      printResult(res);
    };
    const updateItems = () => {
      // update the first 2 items
      const itemsToUpdate = [];
      gridApi.value.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(function (rowNode, index) {
        // only do first 2
        if (index >= 2) {
          return;
        }
        const data = rowNode.data;
        data.price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20000 + 20000);
        itemsToUpdate.push(data);
      });
      const res = gridApi.value.applyTransaction({ update: itemsToUpdate });
      printResult(res);
    };
    const onRemoveSelected = () => {
      const selectedData = gridApi.value.getSelectedRows();
      const res = gridApi.value.applyTransaction({ remove: selectedData });
      printResult(res);
    };
    const onGridReady = (params) => {
      gridApi.value = params.api;
    };

    return {
      columnDefs,
      gridApi,
      defaultColDef,
      rowData,
      rowSelection,
      onGridReady,
      themeClass:
        "ag-theme-quartz",
      getRowData,
      getRowId,
      clearData,
      addItems,
      updateItems,
      onRemoveSelected,
    };
  },
};

window.createNewRowData = function createNewRowData() {
  const newData = {
    make: "Toyota ",
    model: "Celica " + newCount,
    price: 35000 + newCount * 17,
    zombies: "Headless",
    style: "Little",
    clothes: "Airbag",
  };
  newCount++;
  return newData;
};

window.printResult = function printResult(res) {
  console.log("---------------------------------------");
  if (res.add) {
    res.add.forEach((rowNode) => {
      console.log("Added Row Node", rowNode);
    });
  }
  if (res.remove) {
    res.remove.forEach((rowNode) => {
      console.log("Removed Row Node", rowNode);
    });
  }
  if (res.update) {
    res.update.forEach((rowNode) => {
      console.log("Updated Row Node", rowNode);
    });
  }
};

let newCount = 1;

createApp(VueExample).mount("#app");


I expect the rows with same id will not get added twice via applyTransaction({add: [row_1, row_1]})

Your createNewRowData function has a hardcoded id=4. It's not an issue with a library but your code. Also please post all the relevant code in the question and not a code snippet link.

How do I replicate duplicate rows with same id if the createNewRowData doesn't create the same object? lol. The entire codebase is already on plnkr.co/edit/8G36oeIsMRNzwPQu like the official aggrid sample. The purpose is not about if it's an issue, but whether this is by designed from the AGGrid team, or an unexpected bug which need to be handled explicitly. I couldn't find an official aggrid support forum or email, that's why I posted here. Please only respond if you are from aggrid or are very familiar with its aggrid enterprise codebase.

@FanChen post this in they github Issues tab, that plnkr will help
